# Combine two words in a corpus with R

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus, text2vec

So here is my code

```
ny <- read.csv2("nyt.csv", sep = "\t", header = T)
ny_texte <- as.vector(ny)

iterator <- itoken(ny_texte,
                   preprocessor=tolower, 
                   tokenizer=word_tokenizer, 
                   progressbar=FALSE)

vocabulary <- create_vocabulary(iterator)
```

My .csv is articles from the new york times. 
I would like to combine words like "new york", "south africa", "ellis island" in vocabulary and not just have token like this :  "new" , "york", etc

How can I do this ?

Thank You

for more precision: I m using these libraries

```
library(text2vec)
library(stopwords)
library(tm)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
```

- and for example about my results

```
ny[1]
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVB68.png) " LEAD Governor Cuomo with possible Presidential campaign waiting the wings took the oath office New Year Eve for second term New York chief executive LEAD Governor Cuomo with possible Presidential campaign waiting the wings ...

- `vocabulary`
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVB68.png)

Comment: It's hard to answer your question from the information that you've given. Can you add more information, including information about the packages that you're using and a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I updated the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still a little hard to answer your question: we can't run your code because we don't have "nyt.csv." But it seems that `gsub()` will do what you want:

```
ny <- read.csv2("nyt.csv", sep = "\t", header = TRUE)
ny <– gsub("new york", "newyork", ny, ignore.case = TRUE)
ny <– gsub("south africa", "southafrica", ny, ignore.case = TRUE)
ny_texte <- as.vector(ny)
```

(And then run the `itoken()` and `create_vocabulary()` commands from your example.)